# How to use date and time values as features to predict a value using a neural network?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I'm trying to predict the magnitude of an earthquake using neural network as a part of a challenge. This is the [database](https://www.kaggle.com/usgs/earthquake-database).

I've already made a pet project for neural networks using numpy, but it only works with binary numbers.

When I try to do this operation, it can be complete because date and time features [cannot be multiplied](https://github.com/cleytonmessias/Make_a_neural_network/blob/master/demo_3_layers.py#L30).

I'm looking for some references about [using dates](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14634/how-to-encode-date-as-input-in-neural-network) but no conclusion until know.

Here's my notebook that I've made so far about predicting the magnitude of [the earthquake](https://gist.github.com/cleytonmessias/e8290c470c28695322224bed08fc92e7).

Does anyone know if:

- I can use date and time as features
- Predict magnitude using some modification of this [project](https://gist.github.com/cleytonmessias/e8290c470c28695322224bed08fc92e7)?

Comment: What pet project?

Comment: @Nils I've updated to make it clearer. This [project](https://gist.github.com/cleytonmessias/e8290c470c28695322224bed08fc92e7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use dates, you could transform them to a float object. You could use the list of dates, which represent your features, to compute a list of values with seconds passed since earliest date in that list. If you take the difference of two datetime.datetime objects you get a timedelta object, which has a total_seconds attribute.

Here is an example of how to do such transformation:

```
import datetime
date_features = [datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 10),
                 datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 20),
                 datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 12)]

# Get the list with seconds since earliest event
date_features = [(i - min(date_features)).total_seconds() for i in date_features]
# Normalize data so it lies between 0 and 1
date_features = [i/max(date_features) for i in date_features]
print(date_features)
```

Output:

```
[0.0, 1.0, 0.42209072978303747]
```

These values can generally be utilised as predictive features in a neural network. It may not be the best idea to use the time as a feature like this. 
As mentioned in the link you supplied, dates could also be coded as categorical data. You do not add one variable and coefficient for time passed since beginning of data, but one per day or hour.

Lets look at the following datetimes:

```
[datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 10),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 10),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 12)]
```

The first two data points share the same value for the time feature, the third is different. You could encode that by adding two new variables, one for each date:

```
features = [[1, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1]]
```

I used a binary encoding, features in the first list are 1 if the event took place on `datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 10)`, 0 else. In the second list features are 1 if the event took place on `datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 12)`, 0 else.